# How to merge similar rows of a dataframe and concatenate the differences?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some rows that differ by a single value, like below:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
A  B  C  D  E
A  B  C  D  F
```

Is there a convenient way to search for rows that differ only in V5 and then merge these two rows,  pasting together the values that differed in V5 to produce:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
A  B  C  D  E,F
```

Comment: What would we do in the situation `A  B  C  A  F`?

Comment: @harre In the case of `A  B  C  A  F` I do not want them merged. Essentially, I want to find every row that is `A B C D` and merge them into one, concatenating everything different in the 5th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're only interested in merging on the fifth column (as indicated in the comments), one solution is to group by the first four and concatenate the fifth.

E.g. using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(across(1:4)) |>
  summarise(V5 = paste0(unique(V5), collapse = ",")) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     B     C     A     F    
2 A     B     C     D     E,F
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

df <- read_table("V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
A  B  C  D  E
A  B  C  D  F
A  B  C  A  F")
```

Comment: I've copied and pasted your suggestion and substituted in my actual dataframe name and V5 heading, but I keep getting `Error: unexpected '>' in "df |>"`. I have dplyr loaded, any suggestions? I am not very familiar with the use of dplyr, pipes etc.

Comment: Use `%>%` instead of `|>` (or update `R` to the newest version)